# Making Rails Debugger's `Step` method work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A lot of times I'll have a breaking test.

So I'll go to the test, and right before the line that breaks, I'll throw in a debugger.

Let's see what it's about to do to, right?

But when my app hits the debugger. And I hit `s` or `step`, it makes the tiniest little insignificant steps. Literally, I'll be hitting the same thing forever and still not make it closer to my objective which would be the next code that I wrote, not how Ruby parses it, or how the ApplicationController runs on a rudimentary level.

Am I missing some important detail here? Or is this how everyone uses debugger?

My apologies if this is an idiot question.

Comment: Hello mr Trip! Posting here to get a hold of you. This is why, we are some users in this question on Meta. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137962/tag-merge-params-parameters-but-c-related-params-params-keyword We are trying to figure out why Ruby questions are the primary users of the tag 'params'. (All info found in the question). This matter is very importent to us. You are probably the highest rated user who repetedly have asked ruby (rails) questions tagged 'param'. We sincerely hope that you can and will help us, in speculating or determine, on why this is so.

Comment: If you could leave a comment in above question, please, I would appreciate it! (A false negative, that there really are no reason, or that you don't know, would also be most welcome).

Comment: I can't speak for Olof, but I'm not, and it's true: that info is valuable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can juste type `continue` in the console in order to continue to the next break point or to the end of the process. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#resuming-execution

Comment: True, but I'd like to "step into" the test to my applicationController code, or to my model code. Which doesn't have a break point in it because my test also touches the same code a hundred other times.

Comment: Why don't you put a break point before and after the line you want to see? and just type `continue`to jump from one to another?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining myself well enough :D . Say I have  120 tests that perform roughly the same thing so they go through the same methods. However *one* of them is breaking the code. So I'd like to put the debugger on the line before the test that breaks and then follow that code into my app to see where it has breaken. If I put the debugger like you recommend in the code itself, then it would get stopped by all 120 tests. How would i know that it is getting stopped on the correct Test?

Comment: May be I don't completely understand you point but I will proceed that way: 1- put a first break point in the test you want to break; 2- run the process; 3- when it has stopped at the first point introduce the following break point to browse further the execution for this particular test.
Does it work in your case?